# How to show selected value from dropdown pagination data in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a problem in pagination I have three dropdowns which I selected the results are showing perfectly but the problem is here when I click on pagination numbers like 1|2|3
when I click on 2 the selection option will disappear and get the default result, I tried a lot from two days but I didn't get success, I want to that when click on pagination numbers 2 it show me the selected dropdown result of page 2, I can't understand what's the problem is going on, this is my code

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'association_id' => $associationId,
        'is_archive'     => false,
        'AssocMember.mem_id'    => $request['associations']['mem_type'],
        'AssocMember.status_id' => $request['associations']['status'],
        $cond4,
        isset($keywordQuery) ? $keywordQuery : "",              
    ),
    'limit' => 10 
);

$members = $this->paginate('AssocMember');
$this->set('members',$members);
```

and this Is my view where I call pagination like that

```
echo $this->PaginatorManager->options(array('update'=> REGION_LEFT_COL));
echo $this->PaginatorManager->numbers();
```

I don't know what's wrong? Kindly help me, I stucked at here, Thanks in advance..

Comment: Does the drop down menu determine the order of the paginated results/what is returned? What variable is this in the script above? Can you post your full view code please?

Comment: @BIOS that was too much code in my function, well if u want to see my full code then click here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520270/how-to-alphabetical-links-works-with-the-different-conditions

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? You included tags for both 1.x and 2.x. Including both will cause people to give the wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

That link doesn't contain all your view code so it's hard to tell. I suspect your issue is that when you click the pagination links, the parameters in the url aren't being passed to your action.

To get around this you need to pass a url parameter to the pagination object to that it always appends the values. Ex:

Try adding this to your view:

```
$urlparams = $this->params['url'];
unset($urlparams['url']);

$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => array('?' => http_build_query($urlparams))));
```